# How to use feathers mongoose query update with $not and $elemMatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm trying updated my document using feathersjs method update by server side like as shown below:

```
context.app.service('myDocumens').update({
  _id: obj._id,
  'data': {
    "$not": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        'year': 2018
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    'data': {
      'position': 'senior',
      'group': 1,
      'comment': "",
      'year': 2018
    }
  }
}).then(result => {    
  console.log(result)    
});}
```

I show below sample document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("...."),
  "firstName": "Adam",
  "lastName": "Brown",
  "data": [
     { "position":"senior","group":1,"comment":"","year":2018 },
     { "position":"junior","group":0,"comment":"","year":2017 }
  ]
}
```

Using above query I try add to the array new object witch contain a field 'year': 2018 if it not exists in this array but all the time after run this query to array is added new object although the array contains already an object with field 'year':2018. What is wrong?

When I run above query in mongoDb shell, it works fine.

Comment: Any chance you can add sample data?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing I notice is that you're using the feathersjs adapter.update API incorrectly.  The reference to your document ID should be outside of your object.  Try switching to this signature:

```
context.app.service('myDocumens').update(id, data, params);
```

See the API documentation for more information.  https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#adapterupdateid-data-params